# Solving non-inverting op-amp circuit for output current (Iout)

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am new to op-amps and I need some help in trying to solve for I<sub>out</sub> in the following non-inverting op-amp circuit. All resistor values are the same, no information is given on the output resistor.

[image: Circuit schematic]

Can I solve for I<sub>out</sub> with only these given quantities? Here is my attempt at solving the circuit.

V<sub>in</sub> = (R/R+R) x V<sub>out</sub>
V<sub>in</sub> = (1/2) x V<sub>out</sub>
V<sub>out</sub> = 2 V<sub>in</sub>

I am not sure how to proceed further.

Comment: If you can calculate \$ V_+ \$ then that give's you the voltage on the load.

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I won't attempt to solve it for you but just advise that it's a slightly tricky problem because it has both negative and positive feedback. Without the load resistor it is unstable. See the voltmeter values in Figure 1.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdxWLn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Without a load resistor the simulator shows the op-amp output going to thousands of volts. (Impossible.)*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4CPXx.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. With a load resistor the positive feedback is attenuated and stability can be achieved.*

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. If you had to derive a mathematical formula for Iout, how would you go about doing that for this type of circuit?

Comment: Give the load resistor a value such as 'xR' (x times the value of all the other R values) and put that into the equations. You can check your results on the "simulate this circuit" link and playing with the values.

Comment: An opamp amplifier with negative and positive feedback is always stable as long as the negative feedback factor is larger tha the pos. feedback factor.

Comment: @Transistor, Yes, I was able to simulate the circuit, play with the values and understand the behavior of the circuit. Thank you for helping me. However, I am still not able to come up with a mathematical equation for I_out without having load resistor in the equation. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Without the load resistor the positive and negative feedback are the same so the amplifier is unstable. I suspect that if you were able to do the maths that you'd find a divide by zero in there somewhere. Solve it using R5 as shown in my Figure 2 and then set R5 to infinity and see what happens. Key to solving with R5 in-circuit is remembering that when stable V- = V+.